# Find and select words covered with curly brackets in a RichTextBox

Tags: visual-studio, syntax, richtextbox, syntax-highlighting

i'm designing a text editor with vs.net 2013 express.
I want to select words covered with curly brackets ex:- {word} when i click on them.
basic idea is- when i click on a word,program should check if that word is covered by curly
brackets or not.if yes,it should select the whole word.

i tried this whole day.but couldn't do it.Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: oh sorry now i don't have it.even could not make a complete algorythem :(